# Suspend not resuming

Tags: suspend

My PC has dual boot Mint (Debian used for several years) and Elementary.
Elementary suspends fine, but unlike Mint, on resume the HD spins up but screen remains blank. I have to use the Power button to force shutdown.

As an aside, when using Firefox, and menu/deskcut, there is no deskcut placed in the desktop folder??

Thanks vm for any help.

Comment: Welcome to the elementary OS SE site! Could you please make your questions only about one topic? That makes it easier to give good answers and also for other users who might have the same problem to re-use the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using nVidia graphics, check if you are using the proprietary drivers and if not, enable them. To do that open Slingshot, type in "Additional Drivers" and select it from the opening dialog.

> If your laptop has an nVidia graphics card, it may be the open source
>   graphics driver causing the problem. The open source graphics driver
>   has some power management issues on some laptops. Try switching to
>   the closed source drivers with the Hardware drivers tool from the
>   menu:

[Answer to: "Laptop does not wake up after sleep"](https://askubuntu.com/a/14381/413066) by StackExchange user [jr0cket](https://askubuntu.com/users/359/jr0cket)

Answer (score 1):

We are supposed not to recommend the intallation of third party ppas, however this makes the configuration of suspend/resume so much more easy (actually, just a tick in a box) that I thought it would be worthy to post.

Install [netext73](http://www.netext73.pl/p/netext73-poczatek.html), which is a software from a Romanian group who sells custom kernels for linux. You don't have to buy their kernels in order to use the fix for hibernation. In reality, you could as well uninstall it after the whole process and you would be fine.

For its installation:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:netext/netext73
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install netext73
```

And launch netext73:

```
netext73
```

Go through the first installation.

Check Hibernate in the optimizer.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/382e76/how_to_fix_cannot_wake_up_from_suspend_issue/)

Answer (score 1):

To fix the black screen on resume, just install the proprietary video driver and blacklist: nouveau (/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf)

After doing this, resume should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your TTY (`CTRL`-`ALT`-`F1`) and try running `sudo killall lightdm`. It should drop you back to the login screen and you should be able to log in as normal. This sounds like a confirmed bug located [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1628929)