# System not returning from suspend mode

Tags: suspend, lenovo

I have a Lenovo E540 with elementary OS, and when I close the lid or put it to suspension it does return. The only solution is to shutdown. I saw [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/suspend-not-resuming) post, but the laptop does not have an Nvidia board.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would solve the problem directly, but it might be worth a try as a way around it.Under System Settings->Security & Privacy->Locking, you could try turning off Lock on sleep and Lock after screen turns off. I had a problem with it freezing after waking up from sleep and not letting me enter my password, but after I disabled these two features I no longer have the problem. The other consequence of that is that I'm no longer prompted to log in with my password upon waking up from sleep any more, which is what I prefer, but that may not be your preference.