# Elementary OS Juno - not resume

Tags: release-juno

I'm using Elementary OS, but It not resume.

I tried install [*netext73*](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/suspend-not-resuming) but raise error: `Netext73 - Not found kernel for your system version`

Output from `hostnamectl` command:

```
  Operating System: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Did someone fix it?